# How to call WebAPI using Port number

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebApi and  deployed WebAPI in IIS,That service When I call web Api by using IP (http://172.16.209.121/Analytics/api/Purchase/GetProcSmartAnylisys…/Quantity/2ed4b08f-1566-4538-b46a-6fb3a23bf50c/01-01-2017/12-31-2017/daily), I am getting error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',When I using localhost(http://localhost/Analytics/api/Purchase/GetProcSmartAnylisys…/Quantity/2ed4b08f-1566-4538-b46a-6fb3a23bf50c/01-01-2017/12-31-2017/daily) it working fine......, How to call by using port number.

This is my WebApi

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Purchase")]

public class PurchaseController : ApiController

{

    [HttpGet]

    [Route("GetProcSmartAnylisysFinal/{treeType}/{basedOn}/{valueOrQty}/{organization}/{fromDate}/{toDate}/{range}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProcSmartAnylisysFinal(string treeType, string basedOn, string valueOrQty, string organization, string fromDate, string toDate, string range)

    {

        ProcSmartAnylisysFinal procSmartAnylisysFinal = new ProcSmartAnylisysFinal();

        return Ok(procSmartAnylisysFinal.getProcSmartAnylisysFinal(treeType, basedOn, valueOrQty, organization, fromDate, toDate, range));

    }

}
```

this is my Angularjs Code

```
$scope.submit = function () {

    $http({

        method: "GET",

        url: 'http://172.16.209.121/mbas50-GCGAnalytics/api/Purchase/GetProcSmartAnylisys…/Quantity/2ed4b08f-1566-4538-b46a-6fb3a23bf50c/01-01-2017/12-31-2017/daily',

        datatype: 'json'

    }).then(function (data) {

        if (data.data.length > 0) {
            $scope.result = data.data;                
        } else {
            alert("there is no data found");
        }

    }, function (data) {

    });

}
```

Comment: that is IP number not port.

Comment: An URL format with port is like this: 'http://172.16.209.121:8000' if you not specify the ':8000' by default it asumes port number 80, so, if you want to do an ajax request to a specific IP and port the syntax should be: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:portNumber'

Comment: I created vertuval Directory,there is no port number for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use cors.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

App_Start/WebApiConfig - Register method:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

FooController:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```